# Azure Http trigger function app works only when stop and restart again

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions, azureservicebus

I have used Http trigger function app, and want to read message from service bus topic.

Install nuget - `Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus`.

But it only read a messages only once second time when I trigger Http function messages comes null.

When I stop and restart function app and trigger it, it works fine for 1st time again for second trigger messages comes null.

Why such behavior?

```
  [FunctionName("Test")]
        public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req,
            ILogger log)
        {

            string serviceBusConnectionString = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ConnectionStringSettingName");
            var messageReceiver = new MessageReceiver(serviceBusConnectionString, Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("EntityPath"), ReceiveMode.PeekLock);

            var messages = await messageReceiver.ReceiveAsync(500, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));

            if (messages != null)
            {
            foreach (Message item in messages)
                    {
           // process messages and complete it.
   await messageReceiver.CompleteAsync(item.SystemProperties.LockToken);
```

I want to use `Http Trigger` only because I have to call this http function from other place so can not use service bus trigger. Currently only one place I'm calling fucntion app so `ReceiveAsync` should work

I think need to use `ReceiveAsync` and `ReceiveAndDelete` like below -

```
var messages = await messageReceiver.ReceiveAsync(500);

var messageReceiver = new MessageReceiver(serviceBusConnectionString, Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("EntityPath"), ReceiveMode.ReceiveAndDelete);
```

Comment: It sounds to me like you need a servicebusttrigger not a http trigger - I will put together an answer for you

Comment: nope my requirement is http trigger only because i want to call this http trigger function in multiple places

Comment: in that case it sounds like you need to be doing a "peek" on the messages which leaves them in place instead of "receiving" them which is intended to ensure that no 2 handlers get the same message.

Comment: currently only one place that is logic app , still same issue why ?

Comment: Have you tried testing your function indepenently of the logic app with something like postman?   can you post your revised function which uses peek

Comment: peek is working fine but i cant complete that message as SystemProperties.LockToken is 0

Comment: updated question pls check

Comment: If you are writing some kind of queue monitoring software so that each time you call this azure function you see the contents of the queue you should be using peek and not completing the messages.  If you are trying to consume the messages then you should be using receive and the behavour you describe is expected.  Reading between the lines it sounds like you should be consuming the message from your logic app instead of using this function

Comment: yes scenarios is call function app from logic app in function app read available message from topic take out name field from message and pass it to logic app to work on it.

Comment: when consuming a message you only get to read it once, so you are seeing the intended beahiour of service bus.  I would suggest you consider restructuring your solution to account for this.  I would suggest changing this azure function into a service bus triggered function and have it write out the data somewhere that the logic app can query it easily such as a storage account or drop the function entirely and make use of the service bus trigger directly in your logic app.

Comment: thanks for brief advice.
i was thinking to read message into Logic app itself but logic app read only 20 message at a time not more than that :( any suggestion on that?

Comment: Its my understanding that when you have a service bus trigger the logic app will run multiple times until all the messages are done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when consuming a message you only get to read it once, so you are seeing the intended behaviour of service bus.

I would suggest you consider restructuring your solution to account for this.

Its difficult to provide a concrete solution as I don't know your full requirements but I suggest either changing this azure function into a service bus triggered function and have it write out the data somewhere that the logic app can query it easily such as a storage account

The second option would be to  drop the function entirely and make use of the service bus trigger directly in your logic app.  This is configured to poll the service bus every so often and will run repeatedly until the all the messages have been processed before waiting for the poll interval.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use PeekAsync instead of ReceiveAsync.

Peek will keep the messages in the queue so that they can be handled by another process, where as receive marks them as being processed to prevent multiple delivery. Restarting your function app would rollback the receive which puts the message back on the queue.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.servicebus.core.messagereceiver.peekasync?view=azure-dotnet#Microsoft_Azure_ServiceBus_Core_MessageReceiver_PeekAsync

Comment: oh got it but currently only one logic app is triggering that function app and still facing the issue first time read and second time not until restart function app.
Let me try PeekAsync